# Regex.Split() on comma, space or semi-colon delimitted string

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I'm trying to split a string that can either be comma, space or semi-colon delimitted. It could also contain a space or spaces after each delimitter. For example

```
22222,11111,23232 
OR
22222, 11111, 23232 
OR
22222;     11111; 23232
OR
22222 11111 23232
```

Any one of these would produce an array with three values `["22222","11111","23232"]`

So far I have `var values = Regex.Split("22222, 11111, 23232", @"[\\s,;]+")` but this produces an array with the second and third values including the space(s) like so:

```
["22222"," 11111"," 23232"]
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

- [`Regex.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx)
- [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx)

In this case, you want to split your string by specific delimiters caracters. `String.Split` has been created for this special purpose. This method will be faster than `Regex.Split`.

```
char[] delimiters = new [] { ',', ';', ' ' };  // List of your delimiters
var splittedArray = myString.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Please explain your comment `Don't use Regex to split a string, use String.Split method`.

Comment: @bflemi3 In this case, the delimiters are very simple (only different characters), String.Split has been created for this special purpose : Splitting string into multiple strings that are seperated by defined characters. I think using _String.Split_, in this case, will be faster than _Regex.Split_.

Comment: This would have been an excellent answer if there wasn't the first statement with "Don't use Regex" and if you had included a regex at least as an alternative. I for example googled to find the answer to the very same question and I'm working with JavaScript not C#.

Comment: A few years late, but for what it's worth, the `\s` maps to more than a space character. It also maps to the form feed character, `\u000C`, the newline character, `\u000A`, the carriage return character, `\u000D`, the tab character, `\u0009`, the vertical tab character, `\u000B`, the ellipsis or NEXT LINE (NEL) character (…), `\u0085`, and any separator character (`\u0020`, `\u00A0`, `\u1680`, `\u2000`, `\u2001`, `\u2002`, `\u2003`, `\u2004`, `\u2005`, `\u2006`, `\u2007`, `\u2008`, `\u2009`, `\u200A`, `\u202F`, `\u205F`, `\u3000`) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#Anchor_7

Answer (score 8):

You are using an `@` symbol for your string, so the `"\"` is being interpreted as a literal slash. So your character class is actually reading as a `"\"`, an `"s"`, a `","` or a `";"`. Remove the extra slash and it should work as desired:

```
var values = Regex.Split("22222, 11111, 23232", @"[\s,;]+")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Regex.Split("22222, 11111, 23232", @"[ ,;]+")
```

this worked for me

Also check answer below, if all you really need is split a string based on few char delimiters - string.split is probably a better solution

Answer (score 1):

To interpret "I'm trying to split a string that can either be comma, space or semi-colon delimited. It could also contain a space or spaces after each delimiter" literally, try:

```
@"[,;]\s*|\s+"
```

This has the property that consecutive delimiters (except white space) will *not* be treated as a single delimiter.

But if you want all consecutive delimiters to be treated as one, you might as well do:

```
@"[,;\s]+"
```

Of course, in that case, `string.Split` is a simpler option, as others have indicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex pattern:

```
([^,;\"\}\{\s*.]\d+)
```

For sample text:

```
{"123","456","789"}
1011,1213,1415
16, 17, 181920
212223;        242526;27
28 29 3031
```

[See demo](http://www.systemtextregularexpressions.com/regex.match?p=KFteLDtcIlx9XHtccyouXVxkKyk%3D&t=eyIxMjMiLCI0NTYiLCI3ODkifQ0KMTAxMSwxMjEzLDE0MTUNCjE2LCAxNywgMTgxOTIwDQoyMTIyMjM7ICAgICAgICAyNDI1MjY7MjcNCjI4IDI5IDMwMzE%3D).

[image]