# Program crashing when storing more than 2 items into Dictionary in a certain way

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, combobox

It's hard to describe the situation in the Title very well but here's the gist.

I have a ComboBox that is filled with checkboxes from the codebehind from the first dictionary. 
I then am pulling the text from the combobox to then find the value based off the key (which is the name in the textblock of the combobox) 
They are comma separated so i am using a regex to separate the values.

works fine for the first one and then adding a second one. But the moment I try to add more it blows up.

```
Dictionary<string, string> selectedCharacters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {   
        string[] w = SplitWords(MC.Text);
        selectedCharacters.Clear();

        foreach (string s in w)
        {
            string fileName = "";
            Items.TryGetValue(s, out fileName);
            selectedCharacters.Add(s, fileName);
        }

        foreach (var item in selectedCharacters)
        {
            testBlock.Text += string.Format(item.Key + "   " +
            item.Value + "\n");
        }
    }

    static string[] SplitWords(string s)
    {
        return Regex.Split(s, @"(.*?),");
    }
```

testBlock is a textBlock I am using to display it on the screen for me. I also have other characters like a ' and some spaces and whatnot in the names/keys so I finagled a regex that would look for comma seperation.

I find this very bizarre that 2 is fine, but 3 is right out.

Comment: is every character in w unique? If not, you are probably getting a duplicate key exception.

Comment: @failedprogramming They are all unique. They are being basically being used from an existing dictionary and none of the names are the same.

Comment: @hatchet i don't think it will complain if it returns true, because the check is on a different dictionary (Items), but the logic does seem quite weird

Comment: @hatchet I'm adding the fileName to the selectedCharacters Dictionary, unless you meant doing something else with it.

Comment: @GrantWinney looks like an ArguementException

Comment: @GrantWinney it's not giving me one, I'm going to have to put it in a try/catch like you said. It works fine when I change the RegEx to  just "\W" and make the keys all one work (like going from Dark Pit to DarkPit)

Comment: Does mc.Text always have a value?

Comment: @failedprogramming it does unless I change it from the combobox.

It does seem to be getting a duplicate key whenever I do more than 2. I can hit submit on the button 50 times with only 1 or 2 but no matter the combination or characters int he combobox I select it seems to be doing a weird

Comment: At this point, it is up to you to find out exactly what exception is being thrown and where it is being thrown. There shouldn't be any reason why you can't do this if you are using a debugger. If you are trying to debug with a live application (shivers!), then you will have to add MessageBox.Show() throughout the code to find out if there are any null values and also how far you can get thru the code without blowing up.

Comment: @failedprogramming I've run it through the debugger and the best it's telling me is ArguementException and that I'm entering a duplicate key...even though it shouldn't. when I just display s in the textbox without adding anything to selectedCharacters there is no duplicates.

Comment: Use breakpoints and find out where the exception is happening and also inspect the values of MC.text, current value of s. http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/debugging/breakpoints/

Comment: Guys, regex is wrong.. See the answer after testing :) @Brian Crawford  see the answer given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through comment sections, what I noted that the problem is with duplicate keys. And problem is due to `regex` failure as described in latter part of the answer

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> ArgumentException  : An element with the same key already exists in the Dictionary.

A solution would be to check for key existence before adding it to the dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, string> selectedCharacters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
    string[] w = SplitWords(MC.Text);
    selectedCharacters.Clear();

    foreach (string s in w)
    {
        // Check whether KEY exists  
        if(!selectedCharacters.ContainsKey(s)){
            string fileName = "";
            Items.TryGetValue(s, out fileName);
            selectedCharacters.Add(s, fileName);
        }
    }

    foreach (var item in selectedCharacters)
    {
        testBlock.Text += string.Format(item.Key + "   " +
        item.Value + "\n");
     }
 }

static string[] SplitWords(string s)
{
    return s.Split(','); //It would do the same as regex
}
```

Edit : Problem is with your regex , run following code

```
String test = "me,you,they,are";
String[] arr=  Regex.Split(test, @"(.*?),");

foreach (string item in arr)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Word : {0}",item);
}
```

Output : Wrong output with empty strings as below

```
word : 
word : me
word :
word : you
(...)
```

Solution : Use `String.Split()`

```
String[] arr=  test.Split(',');
```

Additional : Go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689044/regex-split-on-comma-space-or-semi-colon-delimitted-string) answer about using regex for a split

Comment: PERFECT! why are regexs so hard? I didn't know about the string.split() method so I'll remember it for sure

Comment: @Brian Crawford You need sometime to master regex.[ Even I'm not perfect with them ;)  ]  It's always better to use easy ways when you have them :) ..  happy about helping you .!