# How to extract a string from a string in c#

Tags: c#, string, extract

VS 2015, c#.
I have a string...

```
string str = "Name;IPAddress";
```

I want to extract just the IPAddress.
I suspect Regex is the best way to do it but I am unsure.

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should use [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Have you tried to Google "c# regex example"?

Comment: Is that always the format? More specifically, is it possible for the `Name` part to contain a `;`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689044/regex-split-on-comma-space-or-semi-colon-delimitted-string i think its same thing you asking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string str = "Name;IPAddress";
string[] both = str.Split(';');
string name = both[0];
string ipadd = both[1];
```

Comment: Wow! Talk about rapid response!  Thanks Mohit.  Will plug it in and try.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks Mohit/

Comment: Hi @user2660121 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think Regex is the best way? Do you also want to validate name and IP address?

```
string sInput = "John;127.0.0.1";
string[] arrNameAndIP = sInput.Split(';');

bool bIsInputValid = false;
if(arrNameAndIP.Length == 2)
{
    Regex rgxNamePattern = new Regex("^[A-za-z]+$");
    bool bIsNameValid = rgxNamePattern.IsMatch(arrNameAndIP[0]);

    IPAddress ipAddress;
    bool bIsIPValid = IPAddress.TryParse(arrNameAndIP[1], out ipAddress);
    bIsInputValid = bIsNameValid && bIsIPValid;
}
```